# How to display CircularProgressIndicator on top of all widget in a centre of the screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Hi I want to display the `CircularProgressIndicator` in centre of my screen on top of all widget. it should be like overlay.

Right now when `CircularProgressIndicator` is visible all widgets move down a bit to display `CircularProgressIndicator` . I want it should be overlay. Does anyone know how to do that ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:roomie/auth/Auth.dart';

class ForgotPasswordScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ForgotPasswordScreenState();
  }
}

class ForgotPasswordScreenState extends State<ForgotPasswordScreen> {
  var emailController = new TextEditingController();
  var authHandler = new Auth();
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                        child: isLoading
                            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                            : new Container()),
                  ],
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                      child: new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                        child: new Text(
                          "EMAIL",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                new Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      bottom: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                          width: 0.5,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid),
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: new Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: emailController,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 24.0,
                ),
                new Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 20.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new FlatButton(
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              isLoading = true;
                            });
                            authHandler
                                .sendPasswordResetEmail(emailController.text)
                                .then((void nothing) async {
                              await showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  // return object of type Dialog
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    content: new Text(
                                        "Password reset email has been sent."),
                                    actions: <Widget>[
                                      // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
                                      new FlatButton(
                                        child: new Text("OK"),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                },
                              );

                              Navigator.pop(context);

                              setState(() {
                                isLoading = false;
                              });
                            }).catchError((e) => print(e));
                          },
                          child: new Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 20.0,
                              horizontal: 20.0,
                            ),
                            child: new Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "FORGOT PASSWORD",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: i think that row widget is main problem try after removing it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) is what you're looking for:

```
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
                      children:<Widget>[ Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: new Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Expanded(
                            child: new Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                              child: new Text(
                                "EMAIL",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      new Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                width: 0.5,
                                style: BorderStyle.solid),
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
                        child: new Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: emailController,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        height: 24.0,
                      ),
                      new Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 20.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: new Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Expanded(
                              child: new FlatButton(
                                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                ),
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isLoading = true;
                                  });
                                  authHandler
                                      .sendPasswordResetEmail(emailController.text)
                                      .then((void nothing) async {
                                    await showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        // return object of type Dialog
                                        return AlertDialog(
                                          content: new Text(
                                              "Password reset email has been sent."),
                                          actions: <Widget>[
                                            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
                                            new FlatButton(
                                              child: new Text("OK"),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      },
                                    );

                                    Navigator.pop(context);

                                    setState(() {
                                      isLoading = false;
                                    });
                                  }).catchError((e) => print(e));
                                },
                                child: new Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 20.0,
                                    horizontal: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                  child: new Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "FORGOT PASSWORD",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
                  
                  isLoading ? Container(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  ) : Container()
                  ],
            ));
      }
```

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. Can you please check and suggest 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61538071/flutter-show-circularprogressindicator-in-front

Answer (score 11):

2021: Although `Stack` is a phenomenal option, a simple `showDialog` will do the trick. It is clean, efficient, and will give you a fade in/out animation. Code:

```
onEvent: () {
  showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (ctx) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          strokeWidth: 2,
        ),
      )
    },
    context: context,
  );
},
```

When the event is completed, call `Navigator.of(context).pop();`. If you want the user to be able to tap the screen and close the dialog manually, delete the `barrierDismissable: false` code. If you have issues with the `.pop()`, you may want to specifically use the dialog's `context` when dismissing.

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Use Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(); if Navigator.of(context).pop(); is not forking...

Comment: wow! really cool solution for quick simple implementations